# malformed sparql delete query

Tags: sparql, jena, protege

I would like to update a data property assertion using sparql, but I get the malformed query exception at the delete statement when I try to run this in Protege. I'm very new to sparql and I can't figure out what's wrong with this query :

```sql
PREFIX m: <http://www.semanticweb.org/exemple#>
    DELETE  { ?o owl:minQualifiedCardinality ?min. }
    INSERT { ?o owl:minQualifiedCardinality “2000”^^xsd:decimal. }
    WHERE { 
        m:Revenu rdfs:subClassOf ?o.
        ?o owl:minQualifiedCardinality ?min.
    }
```

Comment: "I'm very new to sparql and I can't figure out what's wrong with this query :"  How do you know that anything' wrong with it?  If you're getting some kind of error message, you should include it in the question.

Comment: the error is : malformed query exception

Comment: The fact that you're running this in Protege is probably pretty important, since Protege might not be designed to *update* data through SPARQL, but just *query* it.  After all, Protege is an **OWL** ontology editor, but SPARQL is an **RDF** language, and not everything that you could write using SPARQL/RDF would make sense in OWL.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [sparql.org's update validator](http://sparql.org/update-validator.html).  When I paste your query there, and after adding the missing prefixes, I get:

> Lexical error at line 10, column 45.  Encountered: "\u201c" (8220), after : ""

If you look closely, you'll notice that you're using "smart quotes" (i.e., “ and ”) rather than "straight quotes" (i.e., ").  If you're not using one, you may want a plain text editor for composing your queries.

Comment: Thanks Joshua but I'm not using the smart quotes when testing the query, I'm using Protege's SPARQL query editor

Comment: Does Protege support SPARQL updates like INSERT and DELETE?  I would have expected that it only supported *querying* the data, not *updating* it.

Comment: Thanks Jushua I didn't know that Protégé supports only querying, I'll test it directly using JENA then

Comment: @sugar I didn't say that Protege doesn't support update;  I just *don't know* whether it does or not (but I *expect* that it does not).

Comment: and you're right it doesn't support updates. I can run the query with Jena but I have an error when I do the update, I think that I'm not using the right format, I'm using RDF/XML

Answer (score 0):

`rdfs:`, `owl:` and `xsd:` aren't defined prefixes.

Fixing that and the quotes, the update parses at [sparql.org's update validator](http://sparql.org/update-validator.html).

Note: the validator prints out the line number of the first error.

Comment: I know I just didn't copy the whole query here. As @Jushua had said Protégé doesn't support update queries